# Populate a column based on another column

Tags: sql

I'm trying to make a table for Exams where it looks like:

`ExamID | Name | Points | Grade`

Where Points is equal to some value from 0 to 100. Now I want to automatically set the value of Grade based on the value of Points. IF > 90 Grade=A...

**What is the basic syntax for an sql query to do this**? I'll adjust it to my needs afterwards anyway.

Tried playing around with the CASE syntax, but couldn't do it. I'm guessing I should use the UPDATE query, not the INSERT query.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Are you trying to get the value from a select? or are you trying to rewrite the value on update or insert?

Comment: JanR brings up a good point. Are you updating a table that already exists?

Comment: I'm working with ASP.NET and I connected my website with an SQL Database through Visual Studio
So I'm guessing I'm using Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 7):

You could use a computed column. Once your table is created **without** the `Grade` column, you could add a computed column like this (this should work at least on `SQL Server`, but you might need to find the differences on other DBMS's sql):

```
ALTER TABLE Exams
  ADD Grade AS
    CASE
      WHEN (Points > 90) THEN 'A'
      WHEN (Points > 70) THEN 'B'
      WHEN (Points > 50) THEN 'C'
      ELSE 'D'
    END
```

Depending on your DBMS you might want to use a **Trigger** for both insertion and updating instead, but the syntax for triggers is largely dependent on the system you are using.

If the `Grade` is only calculated and you don't really need to store it, you could use a `View` instead, or directly create it when querying the table and just not have a `Grade` column at all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the UPDATE below find the syntax.You must write the code on the curly braces as given on editor

```
update [Tablename] set Grade = 'A' where points >90;

update Examgrades set Grade = 'A' where points >90;
```

Comment: That's not what the question is asking. He is asking to **automatically** do this.

Comment: If I make a trigger that would go on every action or something similar, couldn't I still use these statements?
Provided that they are triggered every time they are needed

Comment: Yes, you can. A trigger could be created for the update and if you like you could also use the function independently

Answer (score 0):

Try this demo code for your desired result this is an update into your table, its written in oracle sql, also you can write function and call it when updating grade :-

```
 create table examd (examid number,name varchar2(20),points number, grade varchar2(2))

 insert all 
 into examd(examid,name,points) values(330,'MILEY',80)
 into examd(examid,name,points) values(766,'CYRUS',70)
 into examd(examid,name,points) values(450,'GEORGE',30)
 into examd(examid,name,points) values(330,'WITCHER',99)
 into examd(examid,name,points) values(888,'WALKER',50)
 into examd(examid,name,points) values(233,'SHRIN',73)
 into examd(examid,name,points) values(330,'LILY',80)
 select * from dual;

 commit;

 select * from examd;

       update examd ex 
       set ex.grade=
                    (select case when ex1.points>=0 and ex1.points<=34 then 'F' 
                     else 
                     case when ex1.points>=35 and ex1.points<=49 then 'E' 
                     else 
                     case when ex1.points>=50 and ex1.points<=69 then 'D' 
                     else  
                     case when ex1.points>=70 and ex1.points<=80 then 'C' 
                     else 
                     case when ex1.points>=81 and ex1.points<=90 then 'B' 
                     else
                     case when ex1.points>=91 and ex1.points<=95 then 'A' 
                     else  
                     case when ex1.points>=96 and ex1.points<=100 then 'A+' 
                     end end end end end end end grade
                        from examd ex1 where ex1.examid=ex.examid and
                         ex1.points=ex.points 
                          and ex1.name=ex.name);

     commit;
```

Answer (score -3):

Build schema first

```
**TABLE**

CREATE TABLE Examgrades 
    (
     Examid int auto_increment primary key, 
     Name varchar(20), 
     points int,
     Grade varchar(1)
    );

**INSERT RECORDS**

INSERT INTO Examgrades
(Name, points)
VALUES
('Email', 91),
('Twitter', 80);

**YOUR UPDATE**

update  Examgrades
set Grade = 'A'
where points >90;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3fd3f/1

Comment: Ideally you should not be saving the Grade since its a calculated field. Better use view on top of table with Grade column which you can compute using the case statement. So you can query view instead of table and that will display the data you want.

Comment: @MaheshMalpani Totally Agree

Comment: Maybe I could use the UPDATE statement if I fill my table with random stuff and then change it with UPDATE?

Comment: @WhatWhatWhat Yes, you can use the Update function. But if the data changes you need to run the Update function everytime.